# How can I stream 360 video file over LAN and embed it in my HTML website?

Tags: html, video-streaming, vlc, onvif, 360-degrees

I'm trying to develop an HTML element to ultimately play a 360-degree IP camera stream over Local Area Network (LAN) on my web-page, however, would initially like to demo it with a 360 video file. Therefore, I'm looking to specifically **stream** 360 video (file, for now), somehow to my web-page with the standard 360-degree navigation controls (pan/tilt).

I've looked into VLC which seems to support not only 360 video playback, but also HTTP streaming, and I've even managed to embed it by creating a VLC stream on my local IPv4 and inserting the following code in my web-page's .html

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="videolan"
       width="320"
       height="240"
       target="rtsp://MYIPv4:PORT/user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=1.sdp?"
       id="vlc" />
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Another implementation

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"  width="100%"  height="100%" id="vlc" loop="yes" autoplay="yes" target="http://MYIPv4:PORT/"></embed>
```

Not only does this fail to load in Chrome's latest version (seemingly due to deprecated features, 'NPAPI' or something?) specifically stating "Plugin not supported", but when accessed via janky IE plugin to view deprecated content, the view isn't the expected navigable 360-degree view rather the raw 'stretched' format, obviously without the exploration controls as well.

I've also heard ONVIF is something I should use, however, have not been able to connect my VLC stream through ONVIF and this is getting quite complicated, leading me to believe there *has* to be a better way to simply stream 360 video files or ip camera stream interchangeably over my website.

I cannot use services such as YouTube or facebook, to note.

Thank you!

Comment: What camera are you using?  Insta360 Pro, for example, can generate HLS segments all on its own, which are suitable to use directly for a demo.

Comment: The camera is unspecified. I only know it will be an IP camera, but I won't be integrating the camera itself. I 'simply' have to create a video stream using a 360 video file so that whoever takes the project over can replace the video file stream with the IP camera stream. I was hoping it would be as simple as switching out IPs in an element, but this is surprisingly harder than expected. Or I'm overcomplicating it.

Comment: "IP camera" is essentially meaningless... you should get more information on what you're working with.  You can't use RTSP streams directly in-browser.  You'll want to repackage that stream as HLS or DASH, and you'll probably need to do some transcoding too.  This requires significant hardware server-side, when dealing with high resolution high bitrate video.  Once you have that all in-place, there is a lot of open source code available.  Essentially, you copy the video frame to a canvas in WebGL, and then reproject it.  https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/web/vrview-web

Comment: From what I've researched I should be able to stream HTTP (360) video file over LAN using VLC to my embedded VLC object - which I've just recently gotten working. The only issue now is formatting the 360 x 180 degree view to fit a 1080p display with the appropriate 360 navigation controls (pan/tilt/zoom). Some people have suggested ONVIF, although, ONVIF doesn't seem capable of connecting to my HTTP stream. I have no experience with any of this so I'm just endlessly trying things at this point. Thank you for your replies @Brad